# Is it possible to copy .class file content to another file?

Tags: java, notepad++

I need to copy one class file to a remote server. I cannot able to transfer files to that server (It is blocked). But I am able to do copy & paste (from local machine to remote machine).

So will it work if I copy the java .class file content via notepad++ and paste inside remote server with same notepad++?

Please advise.

Comment: Just encode in base64 before to be sure that data won't be damaged.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is here:
https://superuser.com/questions/349345/how-can-i-copy-binary-data-in-windows-preferably-with-notepad

(use `paste special` menu items in notepad `Edit` tab).

Make sure that files size are same after saving.

Comment: re "make sure that the files sizes are the same" -- better yet, do an md5sum on them

Comment: Better make a copy of file and rename :)

Comment: User can not upload file to the server.